# Python looping over same element multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am making a program that takes in a peace of input and changes each letter in it by some amount. However for soem reason when I input 123 into it, it gives back an output of 444.

```
l = ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
n = ("1234567890")
v = ("aeiou")
cons = list(l)
vowels = list(v)
numbers = list(n)


message = input("What do you want to encrypt: ")
encrypt_cons = int(input(("By how much should we shift the consonants: ")))
encrypt_vowels = int(input("By how much should we encrypt the vowels: "))
encrypt_number = int(input("By how much should we encrypt the numbers: "))



for i in message:
    if i in cons:
        message = message.replace(str(i), str(cons[(cons.index(i)+encrypt_cons) % len(cons)]))
    if i in vowels:
        message = message.replace(str(i), str(vowels[vowels.index(i)+encrypt_cons % len(vowels)]))
    if i in numbers:
        message = message.replace(i, str(numbers[numbers.index(i) + encrypt_number % len(numbers)]))
    else:
        pass


print(message)
```

When I input `message` as 123 and `encrypt_numbers` as 1 for some reason am getting 444.
This actually happens for every number that increases by 1 each digit. for example 234 becomes 555 and 345 becomes 666
This works for everything else so I don`t see why it`s not working for 123

Comment: Because `replace` changes *all* occurrences of the character in the string. The first iteration changes `123` to `223`; the second iteration changes it to `333`; and the third to `444`.

Comment: To fix this, build a new string instead of using `replace` on the current one.